# Why did my papers get repeatedly put on the last day and the last session of a conference?

Tags: conference

My paper got accepted normally (e.g., with neutral to positive reviewer rating) to a conference.

I have noticed that, I always get to present (oral or poster) on the last days of the conference, and worse, at the last session.

Predictably, I did not get a large audience, and got fewer questions/useful feedback compared to papers presented on the first, and second day of the conference.

Does that indicate (low) perception of my paper by the conference organizer?

It is almost as if they want to conceal my paper. The conferences are ranked typical B-level with ca. 50% acceptance rate.

What can I do?

Comment: Are you saying that this has happened multiple times, at different conferences? Are you suggesting that the organizers of the different conferences have conspired against you?

Comment: Is your name or surname starting with X/Y/Z? it may be a very unlucky crossfeedback between your session of choice and your name.

Comment: How many instances are we talking about? What is a B-level conference? What field are you in?

Comment: It may be nothing to do with the perceived quality of the paper, but more to do with the perceived level of interest in the subject matter, or of your personal "brand recognition". FWIW I once travelled half way across the world to a conference to find my slot moved to 8am on the last day after the conference dinner, and I had an audience of 7.

Comment: No, I did not mean "conceal" in conspiratorial way. More in the sense I suspect they think the paper is of low relevant, or perhaps quality (ouch!)  so it's only there for meeting quota. I rather not be specific about the conference name, but I have counted 4 instances so far (one of them put me on the last day, but not last slot, to be fair). The field is computer vision. My name is not on the last alphabet no. @Michael Kay, I'm just a second year phd student, so obviously I have no "personal brand" to speak of.

Comment: It's probably not your papers, but the general subject which gets pushed into late session.

Comment: Does your name begin in a letter near the end of the alphabet? It's not likely for conferences to order the presentations in alphabetical order, but it could be a very distinct possibility which we could clear up.

Comment: too short for an answer: as an organiser you want the last speaker to be a good speaker since the last talk will be remembered more. So it could also be some form of appreciation of your abilities as a speaker.

Comment: I have heard that at certain physics conferences, they put all the "crank" papers in a certain session, so the cranks are there talking to each other.

Comment: It is most likely chance. I've organized conferences, and the schedule is typically made by grouping accepted papers into topics, and laying out the topics over the available sessions, without paying attention to who wrote the papers or their score. The score is often used to decide between oral and poster (which I think is silly, because the score is not related to how suitable the paper is for either), but I have never seen anyone put into the last session out of spite.

Comment: How many times has this happened? Is it multiple instances of the same conference, or multiple completely different conferences, or a mix?

Comment: To expand on @MichaelKay's and your own points, is it possible that your paper could be categorized as being of relatively low relevance to the organizers and/or audience of conf? Is your work is too arcane or abstract relative to the conference’s ideal attendee? You may or may not already do this - consider optimizing your paper's abstract and/or contents for this "ideal attendee," if you're not already doing it. Consider dumbing it down a bit if needed, compare your paper to those of the first speakers to make note of any diffs

"If you don't like how the table is set, turn over the table"

Comment: "The field is computer vision." - how much is there to say about image recognition software that isn't already extant and proprietary? What were the other fields that beat you out? AI, *eleven G*, and cluster satellites? IR was hot stuff... back when we were fighting a cold war. Now my phone can do it, so....

Comment: @Christian: At the conferences I know, many people already have left on the last day.

Comment: @Mazura : there can be new problems and novel solutions even in computer vision. I worked on a project specializing in detecting forgeries, especially where parts of different photos were placed together in the same image. The field itself is not new, but as better methods arise in making forgeries harder to detect, so is the field of detecting them advancing.

Answer (score 29):

Your question has just made me doubt any conference I have presented at - I have been in the last session so many, many times and I always considered it just bad luck (getting a talk in the first place was the exiting bit).

While some of the other answers have already given you a nice perspective regarding the considerations that many conference organizers may have had when they were putting together the schedule, let me also offer my perspective, having now organized multiple different conferences and symposia, big and small: in none of these cases have we put together the schedule based on whether we considered talks selected from abstracts to have lower or higher impact or significance. As an organizer, I want my last session to be as strong as the first, if possible, because nobody wants an empty room towards the end of the conference (what has happened therefore: putting an awesome keynote speaker or exciting invited talk at the end to make sure nobody heads home).

Even when picking best speaker awards I've often been in last minute hushed discussions as we considered a talk from one of the last sections without a coffee break in between the session and the actual award ceremony.

I do agree that it sucks to be on the last day because you lack the free conference wide exposure you might get by presenting on the first day, but there are other ways to put yourself out there: sit with people you don't know at breakfast/lunch/dinner, be active and introduce yourself to people at poster sessions etc. etc.

So, don't get worked up over it, don't read too much into it and just focus on the contents of your work and on genuinely getting to know people in your field.

Comment: Thank you for the encouraging explanation. I did try to speak to people with similar sub-topic in the first/second day of  the conference (i.e., after their oral or during their poster session). Sometimes 
I casually bringing up my works, and if I'm lucky I get the feedback that I need. A lot of them were already gone by the third day! So to whoever shares  the same fate as me, this is the least you can do. :)

Comment: "none of these cases have we put together the schedule based on talks we considered to have lower or higher impact" seems to contradict with "the opposite has happened: ..."

Comment: +1 for the clustering by topic, and the odds and ends/not enough talks to fill one whole session. This has been my experience as well. Sometimes to the detriment of the clustered sessions as no 'new' people would attend those.

Comment: @DanM. well spotted, edited for clarity.

Answer (score 11):

How do conferences group papers?

(Based on my experience and therefore subjective)

Usually, the programming committee has a meeting to discuss referee reports. On rare occasion, last-minute reviews are being done by PC members to balance the fact that reviewers did not respond timely or in order to understand the review reports better. Before the meeting, the PC chair might divide the submissions into three groups: definitely accept, where the PC is expected to rubber-stamp this decision, definitely do not accept, for instance, because none of the three reviewers voted for a straight accept, or as desk-rejects, and the papers that ought to be discussed. In parallel, the number of papers to be selected is determined.

When the work is done, the Chair with or without help groups papers together by threads. Some papers will cluster naturally, and sometimes they will not, leading to "Odds and Ends" sessions. After the sessions have been determined, they get assigned to dates in the calendar. Even if there is no Best Paper award, the papers that according to the PC and the reviewers are or were candidates, have their session placed in the prime time, usually a session after the key-note talk. Everything else gets a spot assigned usually without much deliberation. Odds-and-ends sessions without a strong paper and without strong cohesion tend to get assigned last session in a day.

Now, big conferences like VLDB and those where the tracks are more independently organized work differently.

TO ANSWER YOUR QUESTION:

It is unlikely that someone is out to get you, because the decision making process is too distributed for that to work easily. It might be a sequence of bad luck (statistically slumps are likely to occur) or it might be that your work does not cluster well with other work.

Unfortunately, the conference method of disseminating information has draw-backs, and you are suffering from one. If you look at the history, conferences started out much more as an exchange of ideas before the developed into the main dissemination method of Computer Science.

If conferences accept your papers, someone thinks your work is worth-while. However, even if you end up presenting in a prime spot, your audience tends to be already overwhelmed by the program and you might not get a substantially better reception.

Comment: No, no, no. I didn't mean "get me" in such conspiratorial way. No one care that much about some unknown phd student, haha. More like, in your words my paper was more than often perceived as belonging to "Odds-and-ends session". If that's true, I'm trying to improve my works and would like to know where to start.

Comment: Working on stuff that is a bit out of the main stream is actually cool. So, with "odds-and-ends" I do not mean bad or inferior quality or "just squeaked by". I remember one PC meeting where the PC was quite enthusiastic about accepting a paper because it was a bit different, even though it fit the call-for-papers.

Answer (score 9):

I very much doubt that the organizers want to conceal your paper. If they thought that they would have rejected it.

I suspect that although it cleared the cutoff point for acceptance, the organizers thought it less interesting or more specialized than papers scheduled earlier. You might be able to infer that by looking at the rest of the schedule.

As for what to do? Approach other participants whose work touches yours. You may learn something; that may encourage them to come to your talk. Try harder to connect your work to questions people at that conference care about.

That said, congratulations on the acceptances.

Comment: I hope so, by conceal I mean in the "hope no one noticed I put _this_ paper here" sense. It is true that my subtopic is more relatively specialized. Yes, I have been approaching people on the first and second days, because often by the third day they were gone!

Answer (score 7):

It seems very unlikely that there is a conspiracy to bury your results at the end of conferences. I think there are a few possibilities:

1. Your work was considered less interesting and therefore not worth a "prime-time" spot. It's impossible for anyone here to determine this and, honestly, its not worth thinking about.
2. The conference organized posters/presentations based on some other factor like order of submission, name of author, topic, etc... Anything could have landed your presentation at the end - someone has to be last and it might not have much to do with quality.
3. Related to 1, are you sure your presentation was *really* best suited to a particular conference? Its always possible that your work is actually quite good but not 100% on topic (or of broad interest).
4. Bad luck. Unless you have a trend spanning dozens of conferences, maybe there is nothing here. We tend to focus on extreme outcomes and you're more likely to notice when you are at the end (especially since you think this is a trend) than when you are stuck somewhere in the middle.

I don't actually think there is anything for you to do. It's not even clear that there is something wrong in the first place. You probably can't go wrong with @Ethan Bolker's suggestions. But really, just focus on producing quality work and identifying conferences which are best suited to sharing that work.

Comment: Ah again, I did not mean "someone is out to bury my works". More along the lines "well, I need to fill some sessions, this paper got peer-review acceptance, but is a bit dubious, if I put it here, I bet no one will notice". #3 is plausible reason for some of the conferences I attend, but definitely not all. Yeah, I will try my best to focus on the content.

Answer (score 7):

Mostly, my experience agrees with the existing answers by [BioBrains](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/196951) and [Thomas Schwarz](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/196948) — schedules are decided by a variety of concerns, with “quality” far down on the list if it’s considered at all.

The one common exception, in my experience, is that **committees often aim to put *strong* talks in certain key time-slots** — speakers we expect to give a compelling talk and/or attract a large audience (which mostly coincide). These slots typically include each day’s opening talk, especially the first day, but also often each closing talk as well, especially the last day’s, to make sure the conference ends on a strong note, and also to motivate participants to stick around to the end.  An unpopular schedule on the last afternoon is a recipe for audience attrition.

So a few of the *strongest* (maybe c.10% of all talks) often have their quality taken into account in their scheduling; but for the placement of the rest, quality is essentially irrelevant to the schedule.  In particular, I’ve never known a committee speak in terms of trying to “bury” bad talks, or consistently put weaker talks into later sessions; so I wouldn’t draw any bad conclusions from the scheduling you describe.